# Validation of password using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Following is code for username.php

```
    <html>
  <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
      <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script> -->

       <script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#username").change(function(){
                 $("#message").html("<img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> checking...");


            var username=$("#username").val();

              $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"check.php",
                    data:"username="+username,
                        success:function(data){
                        if(data==0){
                            $("#message").html("Username available");
                        }
                        else{
                            $("#message").html("Username already taken");
                        }
                    }
                 });

            });

         });

       </script>
  </head>

  <body>

       <table>
        <tr>
              <td>Username</td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="id" id="username""/><td>
                <td id="message"><td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
              <td>Password</td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="password" id="password" /><td>
        </tr>
       </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the code for check.php

```
    <?php

  mysql_connect("localhost","healhmate","healthmate");
  mysql_select_db("hmdb");
  if(isset($_POST['id']))
  $username=$_POST['id'];
  $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from user where id='$username' ");

  $find=mysql_num_rows($query);

  echo $find;

?>
```

this code gives output as username and password boxes. I have included all the 3 files ajax-loader.gif, username.php and check.php in one single folder.On entering username no validation is performed. Can anyone help me to figure out why is this happening?

Comment: dont you wish to to validate password as well? your code only does username check.

Comment: Beware of Bobby Tables: http://bobby-tables.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 <?php

  mysql_connect("localhost","healhmate","healthmate");
  mysql_select_db("hmdb");
  if(isset($_POST['username']))// because in ajax you send username not id
  $username=$_POST['username'];
  $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from user where id='$username' ");

  $find=mysql_num_rows($query);

  echo $find;

?>
```

Comment: This still has a sql injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 2):

Use  `data:"id="+username` in Ajax request because that is the POST variable your checking in PHP.

Also on a side note:
Make sure you handle a case where $_POST['username'] is not set.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","healhmate","healthmate");
mysql_select_db("hmdb");
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {// because in ajax you send username not id
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from user where id='$username' ");
    $find=mysql_num_rows($query);
   echo $find;
} else {
    echo "-1";
}
?>
```

And do not use mysql_* functions. They are deprecated. Use mysqli_* functions or PDO.